# Possible to use regex with JSON and AJAX?

Tags: json, regex, ajax

#### The Problem

Within an AJAX call, I am trying to retrieve a JSON object with an appended auto-generated identifier. Is it possible to use regex to select a JSON object that starts with a specific string?

E.g. below targeting `announcements_414988813`

#### jQuery

```
const parent = $('.c-banner');
let data;

$.getJSON('path_to_data.json', function (result) {
    const data = result["jcr:content"]["parsys"];
    const announcement = data["/^/announcements"];
    let date = announcement.eventDate;

    let _html = "";
    _html += '<p>' + date + '</p>';

    parent.append(_html);
});
```

#### JSON

```
{
  "jcr:content": {
    "parsys": {
      "announcements_414988813": {
        "eventDate": "Fri Jan 18 2019 00:00:00 GMT-1000",
        "title": "Pizza Day!",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've extracted the `data` object, you should be able to loop through its keys and find the one that matches.

```
var announcement = {}

for (key in data) {
    if (key.match(/^announcements/)) {
        announcement = data[key];
    }
}
```

Note that if your `parsys` object has multiple announcements, this would give you the last one. `announcement` will just remain an empty object if it doesn't find any. (Break out of the loop if you want the first one, or save them all in an array if you need them all.)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, @BilltheLizard!